# MQTTnet poor performance when multi-threaded despite same number of messages being sent

Tags: mqttnet

I am sending around 20,000 messages per second, these can be across a number of arbitary threads (the messages are processed before sending to MQTTnet).

I have found, that the fewer the threads the better the performance, going over 16 simultanous senders causes MQTTnet to grind to a halt even with 10k messages per second.

It is not the threads that are slow, I poll the MQTTnet Managed Client buffer size every 10 seconds and see it increasing to the point where it becomes full (at the limit that I have set).

This is with the most recent code version and something I noticed a number of months ago (from today August 2020) - it was highlighted with my recent ThreadRipper system upgrade and my code creating number of threads equal to the number of Environment Processors - same code base but 8 with previous hardware with 48 on new hardware caused the "failure".

48 decode/send threads caused MQTTnet to grind to a halt, whereas 4 to 8 threads was OK and performant. I can see the speed on the NIC to the MQTT server drop from 8Mbps (with 4 to 8 sending threads) to less than 100kbps when higher thread counts are used.

Local or remote MQTT server makes no difference - as mentioned I can see the send buffer within MQTT increase and will do so until memory exhaustion unless a limit is set (either way, it will drop messages once under duress from threads and in this state).

Note, in both cases, the total number of messages being sent per second remained the same - the only variable was the number of worker threads the messages were being sent from.

Is this a bug, or something I am doing wrong? Should i create my own queue to front-end the managed client and dispatch one at a time (i don't want to reinvent the wheel, but want to ensure i am using the library correctly).

Answer (score 0):

I have found this seems to be related to debug and start without debugs - starting without debug is magnitudes faster and can scale all the way to 48 threads (as per the environment processor count) without any issue when started without debug without any queuing whatsoever.

Strange, as the message volume is the same in both cases, only difference being the thread count as mentioned (and even with debug and 8 threads, debug can keep up without issue).

Seems there is an overhead when debugging with multiple sending threads - which may be obvious but couldn't find where this was warned.